# What could be causing water to back up into my bathroom basin?

Tags: plumbing

out of the blue, water just started pumping out of my bathroom basin drain flowing over the counter top onto the floor - nothing had been turned - this is a highrise condo I'm on the 3rd floor - maintenance says there must be a clog in my pipe that connects to the building pipe but how could that much water all of a sudden come out of my drain ? I'm thinking the building pipe is clogged.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are on the third floor but do not say whether or not there are floors above you. If there are, and this began while you were not running water, then I agree that this is probably a building issue rather than a local clog.

Comment: He did say a high-rise condo... so I think it's safe to assume there are other condos above.